# Is there an updated rails_sql_views gem for rails 3.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, sql-view

I need the functionality provided by the rails_sql_views gem.  However it looks like the last commit for this gem was made in 2010.  Has this project been outdated by a new project?  I'd like to find an active gem to use to get this functionality.

http://activewarehouse.rubyforge.org/rails_sql_views/ 
http://rubygems.org/gems/rails_sql_views

After further research here is a Rails 3 candidate for similar functionality:
https://github.com/bradphelan/Active-Illusion

This is a gem of this blog post:
http://xtargets.com/2011/08/02/tableless-views-with-active-record/

However this solution doesn't seem to be very popular.

Answer (score 2):

schema_plus gem has create_view method that seems compatible (although I'm not familiar with rails_sql_views).

Comment: schema_plus seems to be rails4 compatible, also; thx for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

barancw, I needed this gem for our product using Rails 3.2.5, so I forked the repo and updated the necessary pieces.  This gem is great for improving the performance of our large database queries, as it  reduces the need to load objects into memory.  I combined this gem with another optimization: [Rails - given an array of Users - how to get a output of just emails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5160232/rails-given-an-array-of-users-how-to-get-a-output-of-just-emails/5161550#5161550)

https://github.com/ryanlitalien/rails_sql_views

Original documentation: http://rubydoc.info/gems/rails_sql_views/0.8.0/frames/index

Please keep in mind the docs are a bit outdated ("require_gem" has been replaced with "gem" and add the gem to your Gemfile as well).

Comment: Thanks for this.  I would get in contact with https://github.com/thbar and let him know you worked this out.  He was chatting with me when I was looking at this before.  I ended up extending Active-Illusion for my project.  I'll post the answer here when I get time to clean it up.

Comment: Our chat is at: https://github.com/activewarehouse/activewarehouse-etl/issues/102